# Access files on Samsung Galaxy S4 w. Android Marshmallow from Python/Windows 10

Tags: android, python, android-6.0-marshmallow, mtp, usb-mass-storage

I'm trying to get access to the filesystem of my Samsung Galaxy S4 by means of Python. There are apparently two different ways to access the files:

1. via MTP using either python-mtp or PyMTP
2. via USB mass storage mode

1) does not work because I can't get libMTP or PyMTP to compile/run on my Windows PC

2) does not work because I can't get USB mass storage mode enabled on my Galaxy S4 (no option to do so, no FIX app from the store seems to be working)

So what other options do I have to grab files from the filesystem?

Comment: Mount the device as a drive. Or, use `adb ls` and `adb pull`. Or, install some server on the device (e.g., SSH server supporting SCP).

Comment: The latter seems to be a feasible option. I'll give it a shot.